# Проблема с авторизацией

Tags: mysql, php, sql

Проблема в том, что выводится всегда Вы не правильно ввели пароль или логин
Почему?

Логин = 1234567890

Пороль = sabedr, который хешируется в sha1.
Выглядет в ячейке так sha1(sabedr)

```
     <?php
  session_start();

   require_once('select_db.php');

  $login = $_POST['login'];
   $password = $_POST['password'];

   $login = '"' . mysql_real_escape_string($login) . '"';
   $password = '"' . sha1($password) . '"';
  $row_login = 'SELECT login, type FROM datacenter WHERE login=' . $login . ' AND password =' . $password;
  $row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($row_login));
      if($row_login){
  switch ( $row_login['type'] ){
    case 'teacher': 
      echo '<script>location.replace("accaunt_teacher.php");</script>'; exit;
   break;
    case 'parent': 
    echo '<script>location.replace("accaunt_parent.php");</script>'; exit;
break;
 case 'scholar': 
    echo '<script>location.replace("accaunt_scholar.php");</script>'; exit;
break;
default:
    echo 'Не выбран тип';
   }
 }
else 
   {
echo 'Вы не правильно ввели пароль или логин' . '</br>';
echo $login . '</br>';
     echo sha1($password);
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему никогда не приходят данные я не знаю, но логика после ифа хромет на обе ноги, перепиши как-то так:

```
// так-же надо выбирать не только `login` но и `type`, т.е.
$row_login = 'SELECT login, type FROM datacenter WHERE login=' . $login . ' AND password =' . $password;
$row_login = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($row_login)); // делаем выборку и ложим в массив
if($row_login) { //если выборка вернула данные
    switch($row_login['type']) {
       // тут код...
    }
}
else {
    // вы ввели неправильный логин или пароль
}
```

В остальном лично я ошибок не вижу...

Comment: вот исправил правильно?

Все равно пишет неправ логин

Comment: Значит - не правильный логин или пароль...

Да и я не писал что эта поправка решает проблему проверки выборки

Сделай `echo` запроса, посмотри какой запрос ты делаешь, выполни, убедись что в натуре - не правильный пароль или логин, сделай необходимые правки(что-то мне подсказывает что это правки паролей в БД) и наслаждайся результатом...

Comment: Уточню вопрос - в БД в поле `password` что лежит?

Если - `sabedr` и лежит, тогда я тебя убью ей богу xD

Comment: так сверху написанно да

Comment: Логин = 1234567890

Пороль = sabedr, который хешируется в sha1.

Comment: в БД хеш лежит?

Comment: скорее всего не хэш, а в простом текстовом виде :)

Answer (score 0):

Вы запросом выбираете только login, а в switch пытаетесь проверить поле type

Comment: все-же, если бы основная ошибка была бы в этом - выводило бы `no DB`, или вообще ошибку аля undefined index...

Comment: а при чем тут no db он из таблицы полей тянет login, запрос выполняется, логин в переменную ложиться. А вот условием он проверяет уже $row_login['type'], а данного элемента в массиве нету, опять же потому, что тянется только login. Т.е. есть только **$row_login['login']==1234567890** и больше ничего там нет

Comment: Или я жестко туплю, или в коде вообще нет массива данных...
Вернее он есть но фигурирует только в if'e, дальше мы пытаемся пройтись по $row_login['type'] тогда когда это строка...

Так что мне не совсем понятно о чем вы, поправиьте если где-то снубил и апазорился...

Comment: ну так mysql_fetch_assoc возвращает ассоциативный массив, ключи которого - это названия полей БД, правильно? Правильно. Из БД запросом что выбирается **``SELECT login FOM...``**. По крайней мере так было. Потому mysql_fetch_assoc не может вернуть массив с ключем **type**. Теперь там **``SELECT login, type FROM...``** Теперь, если результат запроса вернется, то в массиве $row_login по крайней мере будет ключ **``type``**

Comment: Я согласен, но во первых - данные вообще не собираются в массив, во вторых - если бы проблема была бы в этом мы бы уж точно не увидели бы `Вы не правильно ввели пароль или логин`...

Попавку по этой части я описал внизу, в остальном мне кажется проблема в самой БД, либо в паролях

Comment: Нy а раз данные в массив не собираются, значит запрос не возвращает ничего :) Ну Тут тогда я с вами согласен, проблема в БД